# What is the affect of deploying a new version of an app to Azure App Service currently running instances?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Azure App Services, what happens to previously running instances of an app on App Services when a new release is done?

Are existing processes allowed to complete in the prior version, or are they just killed off?

I’m trying without success to find the answer to this online.

Comment: Hi @Ben Chesnut was below answer helpful? Could it serve as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you are deploying a new version app to Azure app service. The deployment probably will fail because of locked files. Because these files in /home/site/wwwroot folder of your app are used to run your app.

You can use below approaches to avoid file lock conflicts during the deployment of a new version app.

- [Run your app from the ZIP package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package) directly without unpacking it.
- Stop your app or enable offline mode for your app during deployment. For more information, see [Deal with locked files during deployment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Dealing-with-locked-files-during-deployment).
- Deploy to a [staging slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) with [auto swap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#configure-auto-swap) enabled.

You can check below document from Microsoft site for more information.

[**What happens to my app during deployment?**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment#what-happens-to-my-app-during-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

After successful deployment instance will be updated with new version.
During deployment/release your app will not respond as the processes may not be running.
If you want both versions running suggestion will be to use deployment slots : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots